# Is there a public speaking web app?

Tags: webapp-rec

To improve your public speaking skills, it would be great to be able to record a short clip of yourself, and have it rated by a web community. I know you could manually add a clip to YouTube and ask for comments on some random forum, but the power of structured voting like Stack Overflow seems like it would be a big help.

Is there any web app setup for this?

Or any web apps at all for improving speaking skills?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try [Rate Speeches](http://www.ratespeeches.com)

> Rate Speeches is a website for giving
>   and receiving feedback about public
>   speaking and presentation skills. 
>   Rate Speeches facilitates two types of
>   feedback:
>
> - Rating speeches, presentations, speakers, and presenters: done by
>     anyone
> - Evaluating speeches and presentations: done by public speaking
>     experts, such public-speaking and
>     presentation-skills instructors,
>     trainers, coaches, professors,
>     teachers, students, and other
>     professionals